# Looking for a reasonably priced wide angle lens

Tags: lens, wide-angle

I have a Canon Rebel XS and recently I've been looking for a wide angle lens. Specifically, anything less than 28mm. Do you guys have any recommendations for me?

I'm looking for something in the $400 range if possible but feel free to suggest others too.

Comment: Right now, this is just a google'able request and a bit of discussion.  If we have some further requirements and intended use, the question may have some value.  For example - if its going to be landscape lens, then a [manual focus Rokinon 14mm](http://www.amazon.com/Rokinon-FE14M-C-Ultra-Canon-Black/dp/B003VSGQPG) may be your best bet, but not for wide angle sports shooting.

Comment: Canon 10-22mm is the one I would recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the 'Tokina AF 12-24mm f/4 AT-X Pro DX'; a new model would cost you about $600, but you should find a used older model for the price you quote.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't your Rebel have the 18-55 kit lens? Sure, its slow, but its pretty wide.

There are very few prime lenses at low prices wider than the nifty 50.

I love my 17-55 F2.8, but it was $1100.

Comment: Haha, I love my 50mm f/1.8 lens. :)